# Secondary citation with APA 7th - Does one have to adpot the quotation style?

Tags: citations, citation-style, quotation

Let's say an author A doesn't use APA 7th and quotes an author B. I cannot access author B's publication and therefore use a secondary quote. Do I then need to adpot the quotation style of author A for the bold part in this example? (e.g. this is relevant when Author B consist of 4 authors, making an "et al." necessary - what if Author A though doesn't use apa and therefore writes down all 4 names?):

> Text Text Text (**Author B, Year B, p. 2** as cited in Author A, Year
> A, p. 1)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You are not quoting A's citation of B. You can cite B in your APA 7th way with "et al."

Why can you not access B's publication? Have you tried a university library? It would be better to look at it yourself.

Comment: The publication unfortunately isn't available anymore and I couldn't find anything equivalent.